# Exporting allocation function to subroutine resulting in segmentation fault.

Tags: c, pointers

I have a device that requires a structure pointer be passed to an allocation function like such:

```
int main(){
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t* params; 

  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params); 
}
```

I would like to wrap their allocation function into my own function like so:

```
int main(){
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t* params; 

  init_device*(&params); 
}

void init_device(snd_pcm_hw_params_t** params){
  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(params); 
}
```

However, doing so yields a segmentation fault. Am I doing something wrong, or is it perhaps intrinsic to the allocation function provided to me?

Comment: The `*` in `init_device*(&params)` makes no sense.

Comment: does this even compile? Try `init_device(&params);`. If you still segfault after that you'll need to post some code.

Comment: `...alloca` sounds like `alloca()` will be used. This allocates memory within the current stackframe only which is released on function exit.

Comment: Don't make changes that invalidate answers. If you have a different question, please ask a different question.

Comment: @MooingDuck I am unable to ask a new question with the typo fixed due to post duplication, and I can't delete this question because of the responses it has received. How do I ask my question properly?

Comment: @ByronS: I'd start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and making a good question, rather than fixing a single typo

Answer (score 2):

> Am I doing something wrong,

Yes.  `init_device*(&params);` looks like code is taking the function address `init_device` and multiplying it by the address of `params`.  then tossing the product.  Function `init_device()` is not called.

Remove the `*` and simple call as suggested by [@yano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895018/exporting-allocation-function-to-subroutine-resulting-in-segmentation-fault/48895351#comment84795994_48895018)

```
init_device(&params);
```

Also declare/define functions before calling them.

```
void init_device(snd_pcm_hw_params_t** params);

int main(){
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t* params; 
  init_device(&params); 
}
```

---

Be sure to enable all compiler warnings to save you time.

Comment: Whoops. That was a typo. My apologies. The actual code I used is identical to what you've posted.